# Retrieving a Django model with only a subset of related objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm attempting to retrieve a specific Django model with only a subset of its related objects that match a certain criteria. For example, I want to get a specific `Restaurant`, and return all of the `Pizza`s served at this restaurant that are vegetarian.

For example, if I have a `Restaurant` named `Papa's Pizza` that serves some pizza.

Let's say I have a `Pizza` model like this:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
   ...
   type = models.CharField(...)
   restaurant = models.ForeignKey('Restaurant', related_name='pizzas_offered')
   ...
```

And `Papa's Pizza` offers the following `Pizza`s:

- `Margherita` (`type='vegetarian'`)
- `Pepperoni` (`type='carnivore'`)
- `Pineapple-Only` (`type='vegetarian`)

I'd like to retrieve the `Papa's Pizza` model with only the `Margherita` and `Pineapple-Only` pizzas in the `pizzas_offered` field.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

If it helps at all, I'm also using [Django Rest Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/), so if you have any experience with that and the functionality might exist in a [`Serializer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) rather than in the model, that will work too.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this via Django's prefetch utilities.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

pizzas = Pizza.objects.filter(type='vegetarian')
restaurant = Restaurant.objects \
    .prefetch_related(Prefetch('pizzas_offered', pizzas)) \
    .get(name="Papa's Pizza")
```

You can find more information at [Django's doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't retrieve *any* related objects by default. You have to specifically do so from the instance via `my_restaurant.pizzas_offered.all()`. Now, that is a queryset, so you can just as easily filter it as you like: `my_restaurant.pizzas_offered.filter(type='vegetarian')`.

Comment: So does calling `.filter(...)` filter on the `my_restaurant` instance?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `my_restaurant.pizzas_offered` is a query for pizzas offered by that restaurant; `filter` narrows that down further by the criteria supplied in the parentheses.

Comment: If I use `my_restaurant` somewhere else in my code, will it only have `Margherita` and `Pineapple-Only`? For example, if somebody sends a request to my server for vegetarian-only pizzas, and I send back a serialized `my_restaurant` as a response, will the **unwanted** pizzas appear in that response?

Comment: You have to post your serializer and view in the question for us to see, to get answer on "will the unwanted pizzas appear in that response?"

Answer (score 1):

You can get Pineapple-Only / Margherita pizzas from Papa's Pizza restaurants as follow:

```
restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(name="Papa's Pizza")
veg_pizzas = restaurant.pizzas_offered.filter(type='vegetarian')
```

The above does the following:

1. Retrieve restaurant
2. Retrieve the selected restaurant's pizzas for specified types

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_pizzas(self, type):
        return self.pizzas_offered.filter(type=type)

# Get vegetarian pizzas from Papa's Pizza restaurant
$> restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(name="Papa's Pizza")
$> pizzas = restaurant.get_pizzas(type='vegetarian')
```

**UPDATE 2**

Request: Restaurant serializer who serializes 'pizzas_offered' as 'pizzas'

```
class RestaurantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pizzas = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ('name', 'pizzas')

    def get_pizzas(self, restaurant):
        return PizzaSerializer(restaurant.pizzas_offered.all(), many=True).data
```

Documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield.

Comment: I want an instance of `my_restaurant` where the only objects in `pizzas_offered` are `Margherita` and `Pineapple-Only`. Does this accomplish that?

Comment: @Quontas of course as `Margherita` and `Pineapple-Only` are `vegetarian` pizzas.

Comment: This is an example showing how you'd get pizzas of specified type given the name of a restaurant.

Comment: I would like to return the filtered pizzas as a field in the restaurant, I don't think this accomplishes what I want

Comment: May you please confirm if the `restaurant` that you are referring to is meant as `Restaurant` model or its serializer?  

if its model then, you can create a method in the `Restaurant` model to achieve this.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to accomplish it with the model?

Comment: Updated, let me know if this helps.

Comment: I think this function performs what I want. Is there a way to serialize `restaurant` with `pizzas_offered` equal to `pizzas`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173690/discussion-between-qubad-and-quontas).

Comment: Yes it is doable.